# Removing # and its value from url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen posts on here to remove the hash value from a url... but how do remove the value and the # itself.

for example if a url was

```
mysite.com
```

and when a user navigates through the one page application the url might change to

```
mysite.com#mytest
```

so when they reload it i just want it to show

```
mysite.com and  not mysite.com#mytest
```

these two just remove the value

```
location.hash = 'home'; 

window.location.replace("#");
```

thanks

Comment: please make it more clearer, give an example of a before and after that you want

Comment: Google does a redirect when it detects a hash it doesn't recognize.

Comment: i was using google as an example. i have reworded the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var href = window.location.href;
var index = href.indexOf('#');
if ( index > 0) {
  window.location = href.substring(0, index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to remove the hash without reloading the page.

Comment: yes you can't if you try remove '#' too. the page will be reloaded.

Comment: i am reloading. its on reload i want the hash removed

Comment: what you mean than reloading? if a url is like this mysite.com/index.php#. it will be reloaded with just re entering url. and after that(refreshing) you sould do another refresh to remove '#' with this. document.loaction='mysite.com/index.php'; and its not good because. 1: cause an extra reqest to server. 2:user can easily add '#' after reloading.and if you want to remove tha you should set an interval which means. very extra requests.